# Tag Geb classes/tests for exclusion

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I am trying to create a simple way for excluding Geb tests from running based off of not having an optional "tag".

In my grails project I have created a "test/functional" directory for my geb files to reside.  Inside this directory I have the GebConfig.groovy and SpockConfig.groovy files.  I am aware that SpockConfig.groovy currently has an issue with being able to resolve classes in the project and only recognises classes provided in the BuildConfig dependencies.  As such, I have created and jar'ed an annotation class "Tags" and included it in the dependencies.  I can now use this annotation on my Geb tests in the following manner:

```
@Tags("regression")
@Tags(["smoke", "regression"])
@Tags(["in-progress", "whatever-makes-sense"])
```

What I would like to have now is for the SpockConfig to find all the classes in the "test/functional" directory with the @Tags annotation, and for each one that does not have System.getenv("functional.tag") in the tags array, to add the class to the runner.exclude base classes collection so it will not execute.

I am fairly new to Annotations and the processing thereof, and so far have not found an easy way to perform the lookup logic of this process.  Are there existing constructs that facilitate such a process, or what logic could be implimented to fulfill this task?

EDIT:

I was able to achieve this functionality with the following classes...

```
public class IgnoreUnlessExtension extends AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension<IgnoreUnless> {
    private static final Pattern JAVA_VERSION = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+).*");

    private static final Object DELEGATE = new Object() {
        public Map<String, String> getEnv() {
            return System.getenv();
        }

        public Properties getProperties() {
            return System.getProperties();
        }

        public BigDecimal getJavaVersion() {
            String versionString = System.getProperty("java.version");
            Matcher matcher = JAVA_VERSION.matcher(versionString);
            if (matcher.matches()) return new BigDecimal(matcher.group(1));
            throw new InternalSpockError(versionString);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void visitSpecAnnotation(IgnoreUnless annotation, SpecInfo spec) {
        doVisit(annotation, spec);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitFeatureAnnotation(IgnoreUnless annotation, FeatureInfo feature) {
        doVisit(annotation, feature);
    }

    private void doVisit(IgnoreUnless annotation, ISkippable skippable) {
        String[] tags = annotation.value();
        String targetTag = System.getenv("functional.tag");

        if (GroovyRuntimeUtil.isTruthy(targetTag)) {
            skippable.setSkipped(!tags.contains(targetTag));
        }
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target([ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD])
@ExtensionAnnotation(IgnoreUnlessExtension.class)
public @interface IgnoreUnless {
    String[] value() default [];
}
```

Using the @IgnoreUnless annotation I can now tag classes or methods as @IgnoreUnless("tag1") or @IgnoreUnless(["tag1", "tag2"]) and, provided a tag is provided on the run command, tests that are annotated and do not have the provided tag in their list will be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip specs that have an annotation, you could make an extension implementing Spock's IAnnotationDrivenExtension.  See IgnoreExtension and IgnoreIfExtension for examples.  Your extension could get the "functional.tag" env var and search for it in the value of your Tags annotation.

If you don't mind using multiple annotations, instead of parameterizing the single annotation, then you might be able to do what you want with the existing extensions and config, instead of creating your own extension.

However, if you want to skip specs that *don't* have your single, parameterized annotation, you would need to implement IGlobalExtension.  See IncludeExcludeExtension for an example.  You can publish a global extension as a service in your jar, for example, using a Grails script like this:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript('Init')
includeTargets << grailsScript('Compile')

target(buildAll: 'build the foo-spock-extensions.jar') {
    depends(compile, buildJar)
}

target(buildJar: 'build the foo-spock-extensions.jar') {
    def libDir = new File((File)grailsSettings.baseDir, 'lib')
    def jarFile = new File(libDir, 'foo-spock-extensions.jar')

    def serviceType = 'org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension'
    ant.delete(quiet: true, file: jarFile)
    ant.jar( destfile: jarFile ) {
        fileset(dir: classesDirPath) {
            include(name: '**/*ExecuteWhenPropertySet*.class')  // 3 top classes + a couple closures
            include(name: '**/ReportConnectionLeaksExtension*.class')  // top class & nested Listener
        }
        // Generate the serviceType file in META-INF/services, to plugin to Spock's ExtensionClassesLoader.
        service(type: serviceType) {
            provider(classname: 'com.example.foo.testing.OnlyExecuteWhenPropertySetExtension')
            provider(classname: 'com.example.foo.testing.ReportConnectionLeaksExtension')
        }
    }
}


setDefaultTarget( buildAll )
```

Comment: I was able to use the direction from J. David Beutel to achieve my goal.  Following his direction towards "IgnoreIfExtension" I was able to follow this pattern to implement two classes which allow me to conditionally skip tests that do not have an expected tag.  I will update the original question with the classes I arrived at.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and posting your solution!  It looks like you could also delete DELEGATE and JAVA_VERSION, since you're not using IgnoreIfExtension's evaluateCondition().